# SQL Server 2008 R2 SQL Server Profiler and "exec sp_reset_connection"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, profiler

Yesterday i ran the "SQL Server Profiler" tool and outputted the data to a table, now when i look in it i find many "exec sp_reset_connection" rows and thats expected with our data access layer!

But what i can't explain is that some times it takes 8 seconds to execute this query...

What could cause the sp_reset_connection to delay that much?

Comment: Does this link over in stackoverflow help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641120/what-exec-sp-reset-connection-shown-in-sql-profiler-means

Comment: 8 seconds would be way too long-- can you see what commands the SPID issued before the sp_reset_connection?

Comment: I checked and there seems to be no direct pattern to this, some times its a select and some times its a update and its diffrent tables..

Comment: @jl01 well its not bad but it does not explain a 8 sec execution time..

Answer (score 1):

You sure it is 8 seconds?

[Starting with SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175848.aspx) (as stated in BOL) `when a trace is saved to either a file or a database table, the duration column value is in microseconds`

**Update**

Came across this post on SO: [sp_reset_connection taking a long time to run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4136717/sp-reset-connection-taking-a-long-time-to-run)

Comment: yes Duration = "8192947" 8192947 / 1000000 = 8.1 correct me if my math is wrong.. cpu, reads, writes are all 0

Comment: Reply to update, interesting but still there are 2 or 3 queries between the 2 "sp_reset_connection" why would that result.

Comment: Are the 2 or 3 queries between the sp_reset_connection on the same SPID?

Comment: yes one sp_reset_connection executes then 2 or 3 queries are executed and then one more "sp_reset_connection" is executed all with the same SPID